# Help needed to solve this number puzzle

Tags: pattern

[image: He]

I came across this number puzzle at vrchat and I am trying to solve it. However, I am struggling to do so. Can anyone else figure out the answer?

Answer (score 3):

> answer: 432. rule: Add the first thee digit number to the second one (in a line) to get a number with three equal digits.

Comment: Probably the right idea, but I think you want 999, so take 765 instead.

Comment: oeps, you are right

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 765

Explanation:

> You need to split the rows in two halfs, each holding a three digit number.
>  When adding those two numbers you see a pattern:

> The first row is 111, the second is 333, the third is 555, the fourth is 777, so the last will probably be 999. (The first five odd digits are 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

> Thus the answer is $999 - 234 = 765$

Comment: Well, unfortunately, in case you can't tell, Retudin **posted the exact same answer** *three years ago*.

Comment: His answer was 432

Comment: Hah! As if an answer difference is enough to distinguish two answers which have **exactly the same method used**. And a commenter even said "take 765 instead".

Comment: He only said it should be a three equal digit number, he didn't talk about the fact that it is the first five odd digits

Comment: 1. People are not puzzle machines that can come up with a new puzzle every second. 2. I have two unsolved puzzles that you might want to try instead of asking for a new one. 3. Sorry about being rude, but IMO it's still the same idea, so there's not too much of a point in just expanding it.

Comment: I couldn't find any of your unsolved puzzles.